# SQL Server : get part of string between 'ServicePassword=' and '&' in a url string

Tags: sql-server, database, substring

I'm trying to get the service password in a url stored in a table.

Example:

```
Parameters=http://google.com?ServiceUN=testUN&ServicePW=testPW&RequestType=testrequestType&MemberCode=TestMemberCode
```

This is where I'm at so far, the 9 in the substring function is only to use as a test length, that's the part I'm having issues with getting.

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(Parameters, 
              CHARINDEX('ServicePW=', Parameters) + LEN('ServicePW='), 9) 
FROM Table 
WHERE TestID = 8
```

Comment: You already know how to look up the offset/index of a string; simply look for the offset of the `&` following the `ServicePW=testPW`.

Comment: So, In place of the 9, something like CHARINDEX('&', the Selected Substring?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    substring(
        Parameters, 
        charindex('ServicePW=', Parameters) + 10, -- len('ServicePW=')
        charindex('&', substring(Parameters, charindex('ServicePW=', Parameters), len(Parameters))) - 11 -- (- len('ServicePW=') - 1)
    )
FROM
    Table 
WHERE 
    TestID = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(Parameters, PATINDEX('%ServicePW=%', Parameters), LEN(Parameters)), 11, PATINDEX('%&%', SUBSTRING(Parameters, PATINDEX('%ServicePW=%', Parameters), LEN(Parameters))) - 11)
FROM Table where TestID = 8
```